# How to get the entity object from RowDataBound in a EntitydataSource bound gridview

Tags: entity-framework, gridview

I have a GridView that is bound to an Entity Framework object. I want to access the object in the RowDataBound event of the GridView. When I try to access the DataItem object i get an error stating Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.MaterializedDataRecord' to type 'BBM.NailArtGallery.Model.Item'. Apparently the MaterializedDataRecord is some hidden property. Does anyone know how to get around this. My GridView is bound using and EntityDataSource Control. The code is below.

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" AutoPage="true" AutoSort="true" OrderBy="it.ID"
    ConnectionString="name=Entities" DefaultContainerName="Entities" 
    EntitySetName="Items" EntityTypeFilter="ItemImage"  
    Select="it.[ID], it.[Title], it.[IsFeatured], it.[ImageHome], it.[DateEntered]">
</asp:EntityDataSource>

if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {          
            ICustomTypeDescriptor descriptor = (ICustomTypeDescriptor)e.Row.DataItem;
            if (descriptor != null)
            {
                var prop = (PropertyDescriptor)descriptor.GetProperties()[0];
                Item image = (Item)descriptor.GetPropertyOwner(prop);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Reflector, `MaterializedDataRecord` is a internal class that inherits `DbDataRecord`, so you can access its properties with the `GetInt32`, `GetString`, `GetDateTime` etc methods, or through the indexer

Answer (score 0):

The RowDataBound code might look something like this:

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then 

    Dim rowItem = CType(e.Row.DataItem, Data.Common.DbDataRecord) 

    Dim myItemID As Integer = rowItem("ID") 
    Dim myTitle As String = rowItem("Title")

End If
```